# Disallow barrel file imports within the same library in Nrwl Nx

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, webstorm, tslint, nrwl

Suppose we have an app and a library in `Nrwl Nx`.

```
/apps
  /myApp

/libs
  /myLib
    /components
       /my.component.ts
       /other.component.ts
    /index.ts
```

I have already set tags in `nx.json` and `nx-enforce-module-boundaries` rule to block importing the app inside the lib. It works and this part is fine.

Another thing I wanted to do is enforcing using barrel files within libraries. So I created a path in `tsconfig.ts`

```
"paths": {
   "@myNs/my-lib": ["libs/myLib/index.ts"]
}
```

I faced the problem. Suppose we have something exported from `index.ts`.

```
// index.ts
export { MyComponent } from './components/my.component';
```

Now if we use some autoimporting IDE feature (e.g. from `WebStorm` or `VS Code`). They will be importing `MyComponent` using the path `@myNs/my-lib` - and this is expected, because I have just configured it like so.

A real problem appears when I want to autoimport something inside `myLib` (these imports should be relative, not `@myNs/my-lib`) - according to logic and this article ([[Interesting article here]](https://blog.strongbrew.io/opinionated-guidelines-for-large-nx-angular-projects/)):

> **Never let a lib import from its own Barrel file**
>
> The TypeScript modules within a particular lib should not care what
>   functionality that lib exposes, so it shouldn’t use its own barrel
>   file at any point.
>
> If a module imports something from its own barrel file, it almost
>   always results in circular reference errors. Therefore, imports from
>   inside of the module should use relative path imports.

So I found a workaround to block TS path-like imports inside lib. I have added a rule inside `libs/myLib/tslint.json`:

```
"rules": {
   "import-blacklist": [true, "@myNs/my-lib"]
}
```

Anyway, it doesn't fix autoimporting feature, just disallows to use wrong imports inside the lib.

Another problem is there are still wrong imports allowed.
Suppose `OtherComponent` wants to import `MyComponent` Then there are three possibilities:

```js
import { MyComponent } from './my.component'; // the correct way
import { MyComponent } from '.'; // not the best, but also the correct way
import { MyComponent } from '..'; // using barrel file - not correct (look at the citation above), but still successfuly validated by TSLint
```

Questions:

1. How to disallow barrel file imports inside the same lib?
2. How to configure IDEs to have relative paths inside lib and TypeScript paths outside (`@myNs/my-lib`)?

Comment: in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript, Imports**, try setting **Use path mappings from tsconfig.json** to **Only in files outside specified paths** - does it make things any better?

Comment: Tried this one a moment ago, but for me it has the same behavior as **"Always"** option. I even tried to restart WebStorm and clear caches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one answered, so I decided to create a simple `TSLint` rule to handle this case: [import-blacklist-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-blacklist-extended)

Rule works fine in `Nrwl` monorepo, but it could be optimized and some mechanisms could be resolved better. Feel free to create issues and PRs on Github if any changes are needed for you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the setting in IntelliJ. I am seeing this work correctly in v2020.1.

[image: setting in IntelliJ under Editor > Code Style > Typescript named "Use path mappings from tsconfig.json set to "Only in files outside specified paths"]

I like the rule @Nickson created however, and think it's a good idea to add to prevent errors!

Comment: After setting this, IntelliJ still imported from '..' in some cases. I needed to append ',..' to `Do not import exactly from`.